# Appbar Button label positions automatically UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am working on a UWP app. I am using Appbar buttons to show quick Icon buttons for actions. 
The issue is, The labels automatically get placed horizontally to the icon while some are still placed below the icon. Is there any way they the label position can be fixed?
Below is the picture for clearer understanding of the issue:

[image: Automatically aligns them horizontal]

[image: This is the worst of all]

But ideally I want them to look like below

[image: Ideally]

Is there any way of making sure they(the icons and their respective labels) remain vertically aligned. Below is my code:

```
<AppBarButton Label="Share" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <AppBarButton.Icon>
        <PathIcon HorizontalAlignment="Center" Data="ShareIconPathDataHere"/>
    </AppBarButton.Icon>
</AppBarButton>
<AppBarButton Label="Add to" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <AppBarButton.Icon>
        <PathIcon HorizontalAlignment="Center" Data="AddToIconPathDataHere"/>
    </AppBarButton.Icon>
</AppBarButton>
<AppBarButton Label="Report" Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <AppBarButton.Icon>
        <PathIcon HorizontalAlignment="Center" Data="ReportIconPathDataHere"/>
    </AppBarButton.Icon>
</AppBarButton>
```

Comment: Why don't you use a Command​Bar to place `AppBarButton`?

Comment: @VijayNirmal no that's not an option as the places I am putting the icons is not command bar appropriate

Comment: When do they get `Horizontal` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `AppBarButton` is used inside a `CommandBar`, setting the position of the label is as easy as setting the `DefaultLabelPosition` of the `CommandBar` to `Bottom`.

Outside of it, there are a couple of things you could try.

1. Try setting `IsCompact="False"` on each `AppBarButton`.
2. If 1. doesn't work, go grab the default style for the `AppBarButton` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299105.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), and remove the `Storyboard` under the visual state `LabelOnRight`. So even when control asks the label to align right, there's no state to set it hence nothing visually will be changed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks :) The style did it for me. changing it to IsCompact="False" seemed a lot of effort on my part.