# Appbar Button label positions UWP

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

```
<CommandBar x:Name="MyCommandBar" DefaultLabelPosition="Bottom">
<AppBarButton x:Name="ArchiveButton" Label="archive" LabelPosition="Default" x:Uid="ArchiveIcon" >
            <AppBarButton.Icon>
                    <FontIcon  Glyph="&#xE72D;" FontSize="14" />
            </AppBarButton.Icon>
        </AppBarButton>
        </CommandBar>
```

It didn't work for me ,when i use the below link :
[Appbar Button label positions automatically UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44754973/appbar-button-label-positions-automatically-uwp?answertab=votes#tab-top)

I have styled my commandbar and hide more options button. Placed an appbarbutton in the place of more options button. 
When i clicked that appbarbutton ,other appbarbuttons are make visible and i need to show label for that visibled appbar buttons

[image]

[image]

I need to show label for appbarbutton on second image

Comment: could you add some more details of what you actually want?

Comment: More details added with images @MDMuziburRahman

Comment: @RoshmiBenny Your code was not enough. Please share your custom style of the Appbar button with us.